# Phrase about purity of a solid substance

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

> Most [high-purity deposits](http://qjegh.geoscienceworld.org/content/26/4/293.abstract) occur within the Carboniferous Limestone of the Peak District, the Mendips. Large areas of the Chalk outcrop also contain high-purity resources.

Is it possible to rearrange the phrase *most high-purity deposits* to make it sound like

> Most deposits **having the highest purity** occur within the Carboniferous Limestone of the Peak District, the Mendips.
>   ?

Do you refer to ‘high-purity’ natural substances as resources or deposits having the highest purity?

Comment: That is more than your source claims. *Most* can be either an adverb, in which case it would have said *'The* most high purity deposits...' ( i.e. extremely high-purity resources/ deposits); or, as in this example an adjective (=the majority of deposits having high purity) occur within...  You could alter it to "Most deposits having high purity occur..." but not *most* *high.*

Comment: You're changing the meaning.

Comment: Most high-purity deposits may occur in the Carboniferous period, but the highest-purity deposits occur in the HotLickseous period.

Comment: High-purity deposits occur mostly within the Carboniferous Limestone of the Peak District...

Comment: Not an answer, but the Mendips aren't anywhere near the Peak District, by the way.  Your original sentence suggests that they are part of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

“Deposits having the highest purity” is correct. It would also be correct to say “deposits of the highest purity”. Most of the time, when you have an [appositive phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) such as “high-purity deposits”, you can decompose it into a phrase with *of*, such as “deposits of high purity”.

Comment: I don't believe that "most" distributes over "high-purity deposits."  Suppose that "high-purity" means 95% pure or better, the Peak District has more than half of all deposits of purity 95% or more, but the Pique District has all deposits of purity 99%.  Then it's true that most high-purity deposits occur in the Peak District, but it's also true that none of the deposits having the highest purity occur there.  All of those deposits are in the Pique District.  (Disclaimer:  I am not the down-voter.)

Comment: @deadrat: I understand that, I just thought that the “most” in OP’s question was a red herring.

Comment: @deadrat I don't care about the word "most". I have a context in which I should use the phrase  _having the highest purity_ with the word _deposits_. I was not sure whether "deposits having..." would be correct.

Comment: @Jon Purdy your answer is comprehensive and clear. You got it right. "Most" is just a red herring. It doesn't matter whether most of these deposits are 100% pure.